# how to find if tables are being read usging metadata query/logs in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We are using DSE Cassandra v4.8.9. I have a requirement where I need to find if the tables in Cassandra are being read using some metadata query or analyzing the logs.
We can definitely find from the application but for that we need to do code change, and we don't have cycles, so thought of considering the ways to get these details using features of DSE/Cassandra if that already available. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain this information via JMX metrics - you need to look to the [table metrics](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html#table-metrics).  You can obtain these metrics via JMX client, or use the [nodetool cfstats command](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsTablestats.html) (it was renamed to tablestats in the later versions) - look to local read & write counts...